# $(window).on('scroll', function () {});

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to show part of my header HTML using CSS and jQuery;

```
<aside id="appNav" class="fixed-top">
<div id="appNavTop" class="appHide">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<span>appNavTop</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
[...]
</aside>

.appHide {
height: 0 !important;
overflow: hidden
}
#appNavTop {
-webkit-transition-property: height;
transition-property: height;
height: 40px
}

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
$('#appNavTop').removeAttr('class');
} else {
$('#appNavTop').addClass('appHide');
}
});
```

it is working fine on my iPhone/iPad (using different browsers) but on my laptop (Windows) when i refresh the page, the section i want to show disappears again and everything back when move the scrolling bar;

need help here; thanks in advance;

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Comment: probably show us some screenshots or add a codepen?

Comment: yes of course; i'll do that;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/user/huntingKnowledge/fiddles/

Comment: "the section i want to show disappears again and everything back when move the scrolling bar" -> please edit this sentence - it's not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using addClass and remove attribute you can use css method with jquery

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 800 && $(window).scrollTop() < 850)
    {
        $('#appNavTop').css('display','none');
    }
 });
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 800 && $(window).scrollTop() < 850)
    {
        $('#appNavTop').css('display','none');
    }
 });
```

```html
<aside id="appNav" class="fixed-top">
<div id="appNavTop" class="appHide">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<span>appNavTop</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
[...]
</aside>
```